# I rendered something but I forgot to select it to export as a mp4, but I can't seem to export it

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I rendered something but I forgot to select it to export as a mp4, but I can't seem to export it, which really pisses me off because I waited 2 days with my 3.6ghz cpu to render my animation just to wake up and I can't export the file as an mp4. Please help asap.

Comment: If you've rendered each frame to an image file you can import them into the video sequence editor and export as mp4 from there.

Comment: also if you rendered it not as a image sequence you can import it to sequence editor